# Counterexample for $H_1(H_2 \cap H_3) = H_1 H_2 \cap H_1 H_3$ where $H_i$ are subgroups of group $G$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a group, and $H_i$ be subgroups of $G$. What would be counterexamples for $H_1 (H_2 \cap H_3) = H_1 H_2 \cap H_1 H_3$ (here $H_i H_j$ means subset product)? I found on proofwiki that this does not hold when $H_i$ are just subsets, but nothing about subgroups (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Subset_with_Intersection and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Subset_with_Intersection/Equality_does_not_Hold).

I already checked subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, $C_{n}$, $D_n$, what when either $H_i$ is subgroup of another, or when either one is trivial group or whole $G$ and I am pretty much out of options. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $G=S_3$, $H_1=A_3=\{(1),(1\ 2\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$, $H_2=\{(1),(1\  2)\}$, $H_3=\{(1),(1\ 3)\}$, $H_2\cap H_3=\{(1)\}$, $H_1(H_2\cap H_3)=A_3$, $H_1H_2\cap H_1H_3=H_1H_2=H_1H_3=S_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $G$ to be the Klein 4-group and the $H_i$ to be the three distinct subgroups of order $2$. Then the LHS is $H_1$, while the RHS is $G$.